# Is there an extension that would show info about current file?

Tags: vscode-extensions

I'd like a way to easily see the timestamp of the current file - and possibly more info. Have searched all around, but couldn't find something like this. OTOH, this seems such a basic feature that I can't believe it doesn't exist...

(Ctrl+O doesn't help, since the list of files might be inconveniently long...)

Comment: SuperUser is not a programming site. StackOverflow is where you can ask programming related questions.

Comment: Well, SO users said it wasn't appropriate there, becaus it's not sufficiently programming related...

Comment: Its even less appropriate here, I'm afraid.

Comment: I wonder why. I'm looking for an add-on of an existing app, that has nothing to do with coding (unless I got deperate enough to code it myself), so I see the point of it not being appropriate on SO. But I would expect that someone who is super-familiar with VS (a aka "superuser") might be able to point me to an extension which would do that. Ofc I did the search myself and found nothing, but maybe such a functionality is just an extra of an ext which does something different and therefore focusses on different keywords etc.

Comment: SuperUser calls software recommendations offtopic, and what you're asking is basically a software recommendation.

Comment: So https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ might be more appropriate.